# Организация JS кода с Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Есть сайтик на php.
Встал вопрос организациии js.
Код условный

Например

**Страница A.html**

**Страница B.html**

**Страница C.html**

**1.js-bundle** - плагин или конструктор(например function Gallery)

**2.js-bundle** - плагин или конструктор(например function Slider)

**3.js-bundle** - плагин или конструктор(например function Accordion)

Получаем

```
Страница A.html
<script src="1-bundle.js">
<script src="2-bundle.js">
<script src="A.js">

Страница B.html
<script src="1-bundle.js">
<script src="3-bundle.js">
<script src="B.js">

Страница C.html
<script src="2-bundle.js">
<script src="3-bundle.js">
<script src="C.js">
```

Соотвественно на каждой странице хочется сделать логику взаимодействия этих самых модулей

```
A.js
var module1 = new Module() // из 1.js
var module2 = new Module() // из 2.js

// Тут логика взаимодействия модулей(не обращать внимание на связанность)
module1.button.click(function(){
   module2.init()
})

B.js
var module1 = new Module() // из 1.js
var module3 = new Module() // из 3.js

// Тут логика взаимодействия модулей(не обращать внимание на связанность)
module1.button.click(function(){
   module3.init()
})
```

C.js по аналогии

Так вот как это все организовать через Webpack и вообще можно ли это сделать?

Проблемы

1. Каждый модуль (1-bundle.js, 2-bundle.js, 3-bundle.js) - это бандл(плагин + обертка для работы).
2. В связи с пунктом 1 - все модули изолированы.

Поэтому не получиться вызвать конструкторы  1-bundle.js и 2-bundle.js в A.js.
Нужно их делать глобальными. Тогда зачем вебпак

3.Можно организовать бандл A-bundle.js в котором

```
import 1.js;(не бандл)
import 2.js;(не бандл)

var module1 = new Module() // из 1.js
var module2 = new Module() // из 2.js
```

Но тут получается свой бандл(A-bundle.js) на каждую страницу, а если таких типов страниц 50.(A-bundle.js,B-bundle.js,C-bundle.js)

То есть если бы можно организовать код так

```
<script src="1-bundle.js">
<script src="2-bundle.js">
<script src="A.js">
```

То когда мы заходим на страницу В.html со страницы A.html, то 1-bundle.js уже загружен и береться из кэша. То есть каждый модуль грузится один раз и когда нужен подгружается из кэша.
В случае с бандлами(A-bundle.js,B-bundle.js, C-bundle.js ) на каждой странице - js файл грузиться каждый раз заново(за исключением случаев когда ты заходил уже на эту страницу)